# MySQL how to specify string position with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

I have ASCII files with a static number of characters for each line with no delimiters. I'd like to use LOAD DATA INFILE to import into my table.

Example of file:

```
USALALABAMA                                                               
USARARKANSAS                                                              
USFLFLORIDA
```

The structure for this table:

```
country Char(2)
state Char(2)
name Varchar(70)

CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `country` char(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(70) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1_general_ci COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Is it possible to specify a start and end position for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html), you can load a fixed format file without using a temporary table.

> If the FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS ENCLOSED BY values are both empty (''), a fixed-row (nondelimited) format is used. With fixed-row format, no delimiters are used between fields (but you can still have a line terminator). Instead, column values are read and written using a field width wide enough to hold all values in the field. For TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, and BIGINT, the field widths are 4, 6, 8, 11, and 20, respectively, no matter what the declared display width is.

The positions are derived from the columns definitions, which in your case match the structure of the file. So you just need to do:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file' INTO TABLE your_table
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  SET name = trim(name);
```

Comment: I tried this with the original example and got strange results; first row: country=US state=AB name= (62 spaces).

Comment: @CorieSlate that's weird, I just tested it and it worked for me. Are you sure that's your table structure?

Comment: I added the SQL structure above. Also, does your text file have 70 characters for each line (trailing spaces?).

Comment: @CorieSlate ok, the issue is because of the utf8 charset. Fixed-size format does not work if you are using a multi-byte character set. And yes, I had the trailing spaces :)

Comment: Great! Setting to latin_1 works. Do you know of any way to automatically trim the white spaces?

Answer (score 2):

First create a temporary table which you will load all lines into it, then you can load the data from the temporary table into the main table and split to fields using `substring`

Something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lines
  (countrystring TEXT);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfilegoeshere' INTO TABLE tmp_lines
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

INSERT INTO main_table SELECT SUBSTRING(countrystring,1,2), SUBSTRING(countrystring,3, 2), SUBSTRING(countrystring,5) from tmp_lines;
```

Comment: Thanks. That, along with `RTRIM()` does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is just assigning a variable and splitting it direct in your load.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfilegoeshere' INTO TABLE main_table
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@_var)
set
  field1=TRIM(SUBSTR(@_var from 1 for 2)),
  field2=TRIM(SUBSTR(@_var from 3 for 2)),
  field3=TRIM(SUBSTR(@_var from 5 for 70));
```

Just be sure not to specify any field separator, otherwise you will have to use more variables, note that I'm using TRIM to clean data in the same statement.