# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE truncates line at 256 characters

Tags: mysql

This is a followup to an earlier question: [MySQL how to specify string position with LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990795/mysql-how-to-specify-string-position-with-load-data-infile)

When loading a long line into the temp table's TEXT field, it truncates it to 256 characters. If I use an INSERT for this same line it does not truncate.

The [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) mentions that LOAD DATA INFILE does not support Fixed-size rows:

> Some cases are not supported by LOAD DATA INFILE:
>
> Fixed-size rows (FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS ENCLOSED BY both empty) and BLOB or TEXT columns.

But it doesn't really explain why. Is there any way to get around this without changing the input file?

Example of line from .txt file:
`012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789ONEHUNDRED012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789TWOHUNDRED012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789TREHUNDRED`

Comment: Is your file actually fixed-row format, or is it delimited?  I suspect the manual extract that you quote is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @eggyal The file is not delimited. Every row is 314 characters. I use `SUBSTRING()` to parse it from the temp table.

Comment: Very well, then the quote from the manual is correct; it would seem that the maximum length for a field from a fixed-row format file is 2^8 bytes (suggesting that the length is itself stored in 1 byte), which would obviously preclude `TEXT` and `BLOB` fields.  Can you not delimit your file in some way, e.g. on `'HUNDRED'`?

Comment: I added another answer to your previous question. You shouldn't need to load the lines as TEXT. There is an answer anyway to this question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the documentation tells you is that `TEXT` columns are not supported in *Fixed-size rows* mode. But as in this case you are reading the whole row as a single field, you don't need to use Fixed-size mode. Just specify a field separator that doesn't happen in any row. For instance, if your file doesn't have any tab character, just omit the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause and it will use tab as the default field separator:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfile' INTO TABLE tmp_lines
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```