# ignore first two characters on a column while importing csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import a csv file to mysql table, But I need to remove First  two characters on particular column before importing to mysql.
This is my statment :

```
 string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'E:/park/Export.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes)";
```

Column `IssueReasoncode' has data like 'LU12' ,` But i need to remove the first 2 characters it should have only integers on it and not alpha numeric . 
I need to remove `'LU'` from that column.

Is it possible to write like this on  `left(IssueReasonCode +'  '2).` This  column is varchar(45) and cant be changed now because of large data on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` has the ability to perform a function on the data for each column as you read it in (q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990795/mysql-how-to-specify-string-position-with-load-data-infile)).  In your case, if you wanted to remove the first two characters from the `IssueReasonCode` column, you could use:

```
RIGHT(IssueReasonCode, CHAR_LENGTH(IssueReasonCode) - 2)
```

to remove the first two characters.  You specify such column mappings at the end of the `LOAD DATA` statement using `SET`.  Your statement should look something like the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/park/Export.csv' INTO TABLE tickets
FIELDS terminated by ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(SiteId, DateTime, Serial, DeviceId, AgentAID, VehicleRegistration, CarPark, SpaceNumber,
GpsAddress, VehicleType, VehicleMake, VehicleModel, VehicleColour, IssueReasonCode,
IssueReason, NoticeLocation, Points, Notes)
SET IssueReasonCode = RIGHT(IssueReasonCode, CHAR_LENGTH(IssueReasonCode) - 2)
```

Comment: I tried your statment and I am gettting Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: @KiranV Both the answers given should ideally work.  Did you copy them accurately?  Are you missing a semicolon, quote, etc.?

Comment: Sorry my mistake csv file was corrupted .. issue resolved....it worked perfectly Thanks Tim....

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)  and quoting this example , you  can try the below to see if it works

> User variables in the SET clause can be used in several ways. The
>   following example uses the first input column directly for the value
>   of t1.column1, and assigns the second input column to a user variable
>   that is subjected to a division operation before being used for the
>   value of t1.column2:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, @var1)   SET
>   column2 = @var1/100;

```
string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'E:/park/Export.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,@IRC,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes) SET IssueReasonCode = substr(@IRC,2) ;";
```

Comment: I tried your statments and received Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: Is there any further trace that i can use to check ?